# When listView scrolling listView.getChildAt(int index) returns NULL (Android)

Tags: android, listview

I try add progress bar download in listview and I did it. Here is my code
AdapterLv.class

```
public class AdapterPr extends BaseAdapter {
Activity activity;
ArrayList<String> listUrl;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Clickdownload clickdownload;
ListView lstView;
private Handler handler= new Handler();
private String NameOfFolder="/DownLoadList1";

public AdapterPr(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listUrl,  ListView lstView) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listUrl = listUrl;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    this.lstView = lstView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listUrl.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listUrl.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    Button download = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.download);
    TextView tvname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvname.setText("Itemt" + i);
    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         startDownload(i,listUrl.get(i));
        }
    });
    return v;
}

private void updateStatus(int index, int Status) {

    View v = lstView.getChildAt(index - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    progress.setProgress(Status);
    TextView txtStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txtStatus.setText("Load : " + String.valueOf(Status) + "%");
}
public String subName(String data) {
    return data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
public void startDownload(final int position,final String urlDownload) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        int Status = 0;
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlDownload);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
                String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + NameOfFolder;
                File dir = new File(file_path);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdir();
                }
                File file = new File(dir, subName(urlDownload));
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    Status = (int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile);
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            updateStatus(position,Status);
                        }
                    });
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}}
```

But when I scrolling listview if item download hide ( not show in screen) it show error nullpointerexception in

```
 ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
```

on update progressbar.
How I can fix it?
Thank everyone!

Comment: Have you tried logging your `index ` and the returned output of `lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` ?

Comment: Your problem solved?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna it run good if I not scrolling listview. log is oke

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK T do not get it. Can you help me?

Comment: @ĐờiCơbảnlàBuồn: See my answer probably help

Comment: May be you don't have child in `lstView` at index of `index - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getFirstVisiblePosition` to get ProgressBar from clicked `ListView` row, add  `ProgressBar` in `startDownload` method as parameter and pass it to `updateStatus`:

Change `getView` method as:

```
ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
download.setTag(progress);
download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         ProgressBar pBar=(ProgressBar)view.getTag();
         startDownload(i,listUrl.get(i),pBar);
        }
    });
```